# Will it be okay if I use my image datasets with 50x 50 dimensions into googLeNet CNN architecture which is recommending for 224 x 224?

Tags: deep-learning, architecture, conv-neural-network

I am new to DL and am trying to train my first CNN models with **googLeNet** architecture. I've prepared my custom image data dimensions with 50x50 but the architecture is recommending to use 224x224. Will it be okay to use the architecture? I don't want to remake my datasets to change the size of the images. So, if there are some other architectures that I can look into it, please kindly recommend them for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the best CNN model for image classification, take a look at EfficientNet architecture ([Pytorch implementation](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch), [Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11946)). IIRC, Googlenet is kinda old.

If your model requires some specific shape of the input image, you can just resize them (for example, you can use [torchvision](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize) or [OpenCV](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/))